# What's the advised way to do groupby 2 attributes from a Hive table with 1000 columns?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Give a Hive table with 1000 columns:

```
col1, col2, ..., col1000
```

The source table contains billions of rows, and the size is about 1PB.

I only need to query 3 columns,

```
select col1, col2, sum(col3) as col3
from myTable
group by
col1, col2
```

Will it be advised to do a subquery first, and then send it to the aggregation of group by, so that we have much smaller files sending to groupby? Not sure it Hive automatically takes care of this.

```
select col1, col2, sum(col3) as col3
from
    (select col1, col2, col3
     from myTable
    ) a
group by
col1, col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes it shouldn't really matter if you do a sub-query or not, but you can look at the explain plan of each query to see if you notice any differences between them.

The ideal situation would be for your table to be stored in a columnar format, so if a lot of queries like this will be used in the future then I would ensure that your table is stored as parquet files which use columnar storage and will give you excellent query performance.

If it isn't in this format then you can create a new table using a create as select statement.

```
create table yourNewParquetTable stored as parquet as select * from yourOldTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no reason to use a subquery in this situation.  You basically have two situations:

First, Hive could store/fetch all the columns together.  In that case, Hive needs to read all the data in all columns either for the subquery or for the aggregation.

Otherwise, Hive could store/fetch only the columns you need.  In that case, Hive would do so for either version.

That said, there is a reason to avoid the subquery in some databases.  MySQL materializes subqueries -- meaning they are stored as if they were temporary tables.  This is unnecessary overhead and a good reason to avoid unnecessary subqueries with MySQL.  Hive does not do that.  It compiles the query in a data flow and executes the data flow.